# on a group with perfect automorphism group

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is called perfect if $G=G'$.

Does there exist a group $G$ such that $Aut(G)$, the automorphism group of $G$, is perfect?

Comment: What made you to think such these kinds of non trivial groups may exist?

Comment: Hint: Do you know what outer automorphisms are? If yes, look for a [simple group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups) with trivial outer automorphisms group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ with $n>2$. Then $Aut(G)=GL(n,2)=SL(n,2)$ is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I know the next definition: a group  $G$ is perfect if $G$ has a trivial center and each automorphism of $G$ is inner. This suggests that $Aut(G)$ is isomorphic to $G$ for each perfect group $G$. In particular, for the group $S(X)$ of all bijections of a set $X$, where $|X|\ge 3$ and $|X|\not=6$. 
Moreover, W. Specht obtained the following result. 
Let $G$ be a group $G$ without center and $In(G)\le Aut(G)$ be a group of all inner automorphisms of the group $G$. If $\alpha(In(G))=In(G)$ for each automorphism $\alpha$ of the group $Aut(G)$, then $Aut(G)$ is perfect.

Comment: What you define here as a "perfect group" is called a *complete group* ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_group)). A group is called *perfect* when it equals its commutator subgroup ([mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectGroup.html)). These are two different things.

Comment: @ Alex Ravsky; Please write full title of Specht paper.

Comment: W. Specht. Gruppentheorie, Berlin-Göttingen-Heidelberg, 1956.